# How to customise the column output based on the select query

Tags: sql, oracle

Help needed.

i have three columns in a table like created_dt,event_dt and amount.

```
dest test_event;
==================
created_dt timestamp,
event_dt timestamp,
amount number
```

a sample record would be

```
EVENT_DT    created_dt amount
==============================
 01-11-2018 10-10-2018  100
02-09-2018  10-08-2018  200
22-08-2018  20-09-2018  200
```

I need the output in below format

```
EVENT_DT    created_dt  before amount   After amount
=====================================================
01-11-2018  10-10-2018  NA                100
02-09-2018  10-08-2018  NA                200
22-08-2018  20-09-2018  200               NA
```

the condition is if the event_dt is greater than created dt then it should display it as after amount.If the event_dt is less than created_Dt then it should display it as before amount .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE in your select statement;

```
select EVENT_DT,created_dt,
case when EVENT_DT > created_dt then cast(amount as varchar(20)) else 'NA' end as before_amount,
case when EVENT_DT < created_dt then cast(amount as varchar(20)) else 'NA' end as after_amount
from table
```

Comment: thank you, is it possible to include 'N.A' , i tried, but it erroring out as number issue when i try to use nvl